# java -cp "lib/*" versus java -cp "lib/*.jar"

Tags: java, wildcard, jar, mainclass

If the lib/ directory contains only .jar files, what's the difference between

```
java -cp "lib/*" ...
```

and

```
java -cp "lib/*.jar" ...
```

If I use the latter I ran into errors regarding main class and I don't understand why. `lib/*` also contains `lib/.`, but is this the crucial difference?

Comment: Are you asking about `-cp` or `-jar`? Your title and the question body disagree about that.

Comment: Your subject line says you're using -cp, but your question says -jar. Which is it? You're doing it wrong in either case, but it's important to be clear in your question.

Comment: `-cp` my bad. no need to downvote.

Comment: Yes, there's a need to downvote, if the question is "unclear or not useful". Since you've corrected it, I'll remove the downvote!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation of `java`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) only a basename of `*` is supported and it only ever matches .jar files.

Nothing in the documentation suggests that "*.jar" is supported or that the directory itself is added to the classpath.

Comment: Thank you. I was under the impression that some sort of expansion was done for `*.jar` as well, but it seems I was wrong.

Comment: Yes add the path again explicitly if you want it too be added as well.